# How to filter a wireshark capture (pcapng) by source and destination IPv4 address

Tags: wireshark, packet-analysis

I have a bunch of wireshark captures I need to mine data from. Tshark seems to fit the bill but this doesn't support filtering (-f) by the look of it, I simply get:

[image]
Using:

> tshark -x -r Run18.pcapng -f dst 10.53.30.41

Is there a way round this or is there some other tool that could do it - ideally producing the same sort of output (bytes and text)?

Comment: It very much helps if you copy and paste text into here, rather than an image.  Then you can format with `{}` and it's searchable and copyable by others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tshark is actually extremely powerful for filtering, and has two kinds: **capture filters** wih `-f` and **display filters** with `-Y`

Tshark documentation says:

> Capture filters (like tcp port 80) are not to be confused with display filters (like tcp.port == 80). The former are much more limited and are used to reduce the size of a raw packet capture. The latter are used to hide some packets from the packet list.

See

- https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters
- https://wiki.wireshark.org/DisplayFilters

Your pcap files already have been captured, which means that you don't use a capture filter on them, you use a display filter.

```
$ tshark -r TCPD -Y 'ip.dst == 172.30.20.8'
    1   0.000000 172.30.20.122 → 172.30.20.8  ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x4292, seq=1/256, ttl=64
```

Note the quotes to protect the filter from the shell.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - eventually got it working with this (since I needed it from a capture): **tshark -x -r Run18.pcapng "ip.dst == 10.53.30.41"**